# iOS / oSX midi connection using CoreMidi

Tags: ios, macos, controller, midi, coremidi

I 'm making an iOS generic customizable MIDI and DMX controller. This controller sends MIDI data to hosting systems.

In Windows, I 've created a virtual midi driver and connect it via TCP with the iOS app. So far so good.

In OSX now. I 've been trying to use coremidi. I 've created a MIDINetworkHost (from the OSX setup in Audio Midi setup), a MIDINetworkConnection and then added this to the MIDINetworkSesion.

Here are the steps:

- I create a MIDINetworkHost
- I create a MIDINetworkConnection based on the host
- I add it to the MIDINetworkSession.
- I create a client with MIDICreateClient
- I create an output port with MIDIOutputPortCreate
- When I want to send data, I create a packet with MIDIPacketListInit, I add data with MIDIPacketListAdd, I get the destination endpoint from MIDINetworkSession and I send the buffer using MIDISend, using the output port.

Nothing seems to be sent. What am I missing?

Thx.

Comment: Does Audio MIDI Setup show that your iOS device is a participant in the session correctly on the Mac end?

Comment: I fixed it. Thx. It was a network problem. Basically, the two machines weren't on the same lan.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it to work, it did sound like you were doing everything you needed on the programming side!

Comment: Do you have any code you're willing to share for OS X?  I would love to be able to use a command line program to connect an iPad to my Mac without having to use Audio MIDI Settings interactively.